# How to return a column by checking multiple column with True and False without if statements

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, if-statement, list-comprehension

How to get this desired output without using if statements ? and checking row by row

```
import pandas as pd 

test = pd.DataFrame()
test['column1'] = [True, True, False]
test['column2']= [False,True,False]

index   column1     column2

0         True      False
1         True      True
2         False     False

desired output:

index   column1     column2   column3

0         True      False     False
1         True      True      True
2         False     False     False
```

Your help is much appriciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for test if all values are `True`s:

```
test['column3'] = test.all(axis=1)
```

If need filter columns add subset `['column1','column1']`:

```
test['column3'] = test[['column1','column1']].all(axis=1)
```

If want test only 2 columns here is possible use `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
test['column3'] = test['column1'] & test['column1']
```